# Is there a way to make a character proficient in every skill?

Tags: dnd-5e, skills, proficiency

Is there a way to have a PC proficient in every ability(not including the bards "Jack of All trades" class feature) in D&D 5e while obtaining the full proficiency bonus? If not, what is the most possible proficiencies a character of:

a) any race

b) any class

c) any background

can obtain?

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Do you always post the above comment whenever someone asks a question that has been asked before?

Comment: In general, yes.

Comment: When a question is closed (or closing) it can be helpful to explain what's going on.

Comment: I didn't need your additional comment. Thank you.

Comment: @TieflingDragon84 With enough time and gold, I think you can buy training in every skill as a level 1 character.